# Python classes (OOP)

Tags: python, oop, python-class

I have classes that describe a trivial menu (there are categories. categories may have sub-categories or may not, in the first case the products are placed in sub-category, in the second case products are placed in category). I try to pick an object of a class that has `products` attribute and its name (`category_name` or `sub_category_name`) respectively. I've found lots of dependencies in type hints especially in `get_entity` function. What can I do with it?
Category class and everything connected with it:

```
@dataclass
class Category(ABC):
    """Represents a generic category."""

    category_name: CategoryName
    
    @abstractmethod
    def get_entity(self) -> Iterable[Union[CategoryWithoutSubCategories, SubCategory]]:
        ...
        

@dataclass
class CategoryWithSubCategories(Category):
    """Represents a category type (DRINKS, BURGERS, etc.) with sub-categories
     (DRINKS - SLUSHES, SOFT DRINKS, etc.; BURGERS - NATIONAL BURGERS, etc.)"""

    sub_categories: list[SubCategory] = field(default_factory=list)

    def add_sub_category(self, sub_category: SubCategory) -> None:
        self.sub_categories.append(sub_category)
        
    def get_entity(self) -> Iterable[tuple[Union[CategoryWithoutSubCategories, SubCategory], SubCategoryName]]:
        for sub_category in self.sub_categories:
            yield sub_category, sub_category.sub_category_name


@dataclass
class CategoryWithoutSubCategories(Category):
    """Represents a category (COMBOS, WACKY_PACK) without sub-categories."""

    products: list[Product] = field(default_factory=list)

    def add_product(self, product: Product) -> None:
        self.products.append(product)
        
    def get_entity(self) -> Iterable[Union[CategoryWithoutSubCategories, SubCategory], CategoryName]:
        yield self, self.category_name
```

SubCategory class:

```
@dataclass
class SubCategory:
    """Represents a generic sub-category (SLUSHES, SOFT DRINKS, etc.)"""

    sub_category_name: SubCategoryName
    products: list[Product] = field(default_factory=list)

    def add_product(self, product: Product) -> None:
        self.products.append(product)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What are you trying to do ("pick")?

Comment: @zufall I try to pick those objects that have `products` attribute. In my classes that's `SubCategory` (the func `get_entity` from `CategoryWithSubCategories` returns sub-category (that has this attribute) with its name, `sub_category_name`) and `CategoryWtihoutSubCategories` (the func `get_entity` returns `CategoryWithoutSubCategories` and its name, `category_name`). I hope that's more clear. The question: How can I rid of dependencies that are described in `get_entity` func type hints?

Comment: Where do you try to pick from? A list of the above objects? `hasattr(class, 'attr')` returns `True` if the class has a specific attribute. Or do you want to recurse into the subclasses and find out if any of your subclasses has a `product` attribute? In this case, why not manually implement a function `_has_prod` in each of your classes?

Comment: @zufall I have a dictionary like `categories = {CategoryName.{CATEGORY_NAME}: CategoryWithSubCategories(,,,) (or CategoryWithoutSubCategories)}` where `CategoryName` is an Enum. Then in the `for` loop I get values of this dictionary and inside this `for` loop there is another one which is like `for entity in category.get_entity()`.